# is it possible to enable the public to upload photos to a gallery on facebook?

Tags: facebook, photos

Im sorry if this sounds like a silly question but I cant seem to find any relevant information anywhere!

My question is, is it possible through the use of an app or a setting within facebook, to allow the public or fans of  a fanpage to upload photos to a specific gallery within that fanpage?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  Follow these instructions:

Goto your Facebook Page's Admin Panel > Edit Page > Manage Persmisisons > Posting Ability > Checkbox "Everyone can add photos and videos to [Your Page's] timeline.

There is also options directly above and below that one, allowing users to Tagging Ability and Posting Visibility.

As far as uploaded directly to ANY PARTICULAR ALBUM, that is not possible without specifically assigning Admin Roles.